# Create a screen, launch a command in it and detach

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I'd like to do a one line bash command that automatically does this:

```
screen -S myserver 
python myserver.py  # inside the new screen
CTRL A, D (detach)
```

I think this won't work:

```
screen -S myserver && python myserver.py
```

because `python myserver.py` won't be started *inside* the `screen`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can detach right after starting a program *inside* of screen:

`screen -dmS myserver python myserver.py`

From [screen's man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

> **-d -m**
>   Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful! I also learnt that this works, as a one-liner, to create a `screen`, start a command, and attach: `screen -S myserver python myserver.py` (previously I always did `screen -S myserver` and then typing the command manually).

Comment: How to prevent the screen from terminating when the command is finished ? Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490508/how-to-keep-screen-running-after-exiting-the-command-that-runs-in-it

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Stefan M is good, but is not quite like running a command within the screen, because when the command ends, the whole screen will end.  If you actually run a command within the screen, then when it quits, you'll be left with a shell.

You can retain that shell with this:

```bash
screen -s "/bin/bash" -dmS myserver; screen -S myserver -X stuff "python myserver.py\n";
```

This will first launch the screen, with a shell, and then send some commands into that shell to run. This will behave exactly as if you typed those commands into the screen yourself.

A more elaborate script is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766301/598166