# How to keep screen running after exiting the command that runs in it?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have the task to start a detached `screen` session (e.g. when the system reboots) and then to be able to connect to it and interrupt/kill the running process **without** the screen to terminate. Unfortunately when I attach to the `screen` session and stop the running command, the entire `screen` session terminates with:

```
[screen is terminating]
```

I am using the following command to start the detached `screen`:

```
screen -dm -S screen_name /bin/bash -c 'cd ~/mydir; npm start'
```

then I attach to the `screen` session using:

```
screen -r session_name
```

and if I `Ctrl-C` the `npm`, the `bash` command will exit and the screen is terminating.

What I want is to achieve a similar behaviour when attaching to the screen as if I would have started the `npm` inside the `screen` session manually:

```
screen -S session_name
```

and then inside the `screen` session:

```
cd ~/mydir
npm start
```

then I can `Ctrl-C` the `npm` command without the `screen` session being terminated.

Comment: Not a good solution, but I cheat and start a second window so if I exit the first then screen doesn't terminate; eg `screen -S myscreen -e ^Bb -m -d bash ; 
screen -S myscreen -x -X screen -t mytitle bash -c '/usr/local/bin/mycmd'`

Comment: Or start the screen session differently, like `bash -c 'cd ~/mydir; npm start; bash`

Comment: Potentially useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436959/117549

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I got working:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -il

# To install:
#   - put this file somewhere in your home directory like ~/start-screens
#   - chmod a+x ~/start-screens
#   - run "crontab -e" and add this line:
#     @reboot /bin/bash -li ~/start-screens

start() { screen -s "/bin/bash" -dmS "$1"; screen -S "$1" -X stuff "$2\n$3\n"; }

start service1 "cd dir1" "node index.js"
start service2 "cd dir2" "node index.js"
```

The magic is in the two commands in the `start() { ... }` function. This line starts the screen, and runs it in the background:

```bash
screen -s "/bin/bash" -dmS "$1";
```

This line sends your commands to it as if you typed them directly into the screen yourself:

```bash
screen -S "$1" -X stuff "$2\n$3\n";
```

It has a few bonus features, too:

- It executes two commands ($2 and $3) so that if you kill the screen, and hit up arrow, it will bring you to just the most recent command—to run the server—so you can hit enter and re-run it.
- It tells you how to add it on reboot in crontab (with `@reboot /bin/bash -li ~/start-screens`).
- It executes the shell *interactively* and with your full *login* environment, using the `-li` flags. In my testing, I seemed to need this both in the `#!/bin/bash -li` and in the crontab `@reboot /bin/bash -li`, but YMMV.
- You can run multiple services within this one script. :)